# Logic and formula of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone please help me understand the logic and formula for the following sequence?

1, -8, 27, -64, 125

Comment: Hint;  try factoring the numbers.

Comment: It could be $(-1)^{n+1}n^3$

Comment: A different answer is $$(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)+(-1)^{n+1}n^3$$:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are just the cubes of the positive integers and with alternate signs. So the general term here is : $(-1)^{n+1}n^3$. Hence your next term would be $-6^3=216$